# How to store certifcates over session?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, https

How can I store trusted certificates for e.g. HTTPS in a manner, that they are still available after restarting of Tor Browser Bundle?

Comment: It doesn't maintain client certificates after every restart or after every update? I'm surprised that it would wipe after each restart.

Comment: Well, at least when I registered queston I wasn't able to remember e.g. self signed server certificates inside my Tor Browser Bundle.

Comment: ah by "trusted certificates" you mean, you've chosen to trust a given self-sign certificate and that's not what is persistent. You might want to update the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

TBB by default won't maintain a record of which sites' self-signed certs you've chosen to trust similar to how it does not keep track of your browser history for privacy sake.

You can go to Privacy Settings>Remember History to override this which would keep a record of the sites you've visited and therefore possibly keep track of your site certificates.